# Jenkins build fails because it is looking for log path defined in logback.xml when executing junit test

Tags: jenkins, junit4, logback

I am getting the following error on Jenkins when I try to do a gradle build of my code along with Junit tests:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Failed to create parent directories for xxxxxx
```

Basically Jenkins is trying to look for the directory specified in the `logback.xml`, but it doesn't have permission to build the directory structure.

I am using the Jacoco plugin with Jenkins for generating test reports.

Any help to resolve this issue is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `logback-test.xml` in your `src/test/resources` directory?

Comment: @bto - yes. I do. Also, I have a application-test.properties file in the same location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using 
@TestPropertySource(properties = "logging.config=classpath:logback.xml")
where in the logback-spring.xml was ignored during Jenkins build.

Comment: Feel free to accept own answer if it helped, so others can see this problem was solved.

Comment: If we give this line @TestPropertySource(properties = "logging.config=classpath:logback.xml") in test classes, do we have to create a separate logback.xml? I have only logback-spring.xml in classpath.